# WebSocket django channels doesn't work with postman

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, websocket, django-channels

Django Channels Throw error with postman while working well with Html.

I'm following [Django Socket Tutorial](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/part_1.html)

"here's the error showing in Django".

```
WebSocket HANDSHAKING /ws/chat/roomName/ [127.0.0.1:56504]
WebSocket REJECT /ws/chat/roomName/ [127.0.0.1:56504]
WebSocket DISCONNECT /ws/chat/roomName/ [127.0.0.1:56504]
```

"Error showing in postman when connecting to ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/chat/roomName/"

```
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Sec-WebSocket-Key: fSSuMD2QozIrgywqTX38/A==
Connection: Upgrade
Upgrade: websocket
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits
Host: 127.0.0.1:8000
```

My Code
asgi.py

```
django_asgi_app = get_asgi_application()

import digital_signage.playlist_management.routing

application = ProtocolTypeRouter(
    {
        "http": django_asgi_app,
        "websocket": AllowedHostsOriginValidator(
            AuthMiddlewareStack(URLRouter(digital_signage.playlist_management.routing.websocket_urlpatterns))
        ),
    }
)
```

consumer.py

```
class ChatConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        print("self", self)
        self.accept()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stepping through the `\channels\security\websocket.py` module, Channels's `OriginValidator` is looking for an origin header, not a hosts header, which is what Postman defaults to.

Assuming your `ALLOWED_HOSTS` looks like:

```py
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["localhost", "127.0.0.1"]
```

Then in Postman, in headers add:

```
origin:http://127.0.0.1:8000
```

And that will pass the origin validator without needing to modify allowed hosts in Django or the ASGI config.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of ALLOWED_HOST in settings. You can put * if you on development mode but it will affect the whole project. Instead you can do something like below

You can wrap asgi.py with OriginValidator (can be import
from channels.security.websocket)

```
application = ProtocolTypeRouter(
{
    "http": django_asgi_app,
    "websocket": OriginValidator(
        AuthMiddlewareStack(
            URLRouter(Chat.routing.websocket_urlpatterns)
        ),
        ['*']
    )
    
}
```

)